# Wrap the x-axis label in flutter chart - Overlapping label

Tags: flutter, charts, flutter-layout

How to fix the label overlapping issue in flutter chart

And how to remove border color in stacked bar

[image: er]

```
 Expanded(
                child: charts.BarChart(
                  _seriesData,
                  barGroupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.stacked,
                  domainAxis: new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
                    renderSpec: new charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
                      labelJustification:
                          charts.TickLabelJustification.outside,
                      // Tick and Label styling here.
                      labelStyle: new charts.TextStyleSpec(
                          fontSize: 9, // size in Pts.
                          color: charts.MaterialPalette.black),

                      // Change the line colors to match text color.
                      lineStyle: new charts.LineStyleSpec(
                          color: charts.MaterialPalette.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use **labelRotation** to prevent overlaping.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var seriesList = _createSampleData(data);

    return charts.BarChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      barGroupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.grouped,
      defaultRenderer: charts.BarRendererConfig(cornerStrategy: const charts.ConstCornerStrategy(30)),
      domainAxis: charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
          renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
              minimumPaddingBetweenLabelsPx: 0,
              labelAnchor: charts.TickLabelAnchor.centered,
              labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                fontSize: 10,
                color: charts.MaterialPalette.black,
              ),
              labelRotation: 60,
              // Change the line colors to match text color.
              lineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(color: charts.MaterialPalette.black))),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. the documentation of this is so vague, this saved my day

Comment: awesome answer.quick question when i rotate to 90 my charts scaledown by over 90%?

Answer (score 2):

This will resolve the white border issue:

```
defaultRenderer: charts.BarRendererConfig(
    groupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.stacked,
    strokeWidthPx: 2.0,
),
```

for labels issue you might consider rotation, in following version the added `labelRotation` that would help some. thought for 90 it will shrink the chart :/

```
charts_flutter: ^0.8.1
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57201589/11551638

```
var chart = charts.BarChart(
                series,
                animate: true,
/// 1- add this to have a default zoom in to solve the overlapping plus No. 2(down)

                domainAxis: new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
                    viewport: new charts.OrdinalViewport('AePS', 3),
                ),
                behaviors: [

                    new charts.SeriesLegend(),
/// 2- also for dealing with a lot of data specially for real-time graphs to scroll on the graph and more zoom in function
                    new charts.SlidingViewport(),
                    new charts.PanAndZoomBehavior(),
                ],
            )
```

my code:

```
          Expanded(
            child: charts.BarChart
            (_seriesBarData,
                animate: true,
                animationDuration: Duration(seconds:2),
              domainAxis: new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
                viewport: new charts.OrdinalViewport('AePS', 9),
              ),
                 behaviors: [
                   new charts.SlidingViewport(),
                   new charts.PanAndZoomBehavior(),
                   new charts.SeriesLegend(
                     entryTextStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                        color: charts.MaterialPalette.black,
                        fontFamily: 'Normal',
                        fontSize: 15),
                   ),
```

Comment: What is AePS in that?

Comment: I think I want something to just wrap the label, OrdinalViewport has a different definition. I want to show these three bars together.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had lots of configuration and performance issues with "charts_flutter". I made decision move to a popular web library chart [flutter_echarts](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_echarts) which take advantage of [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) and their open source amazing library with a lot more configuration options. I purely moved for configuration issues and I was thinking that might hit to performance issue (because of whole webview concept) but fortunately I haven't. Highly recommended to check it out.

**note:** this change was not easy from data structure point of view since [echart](https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html) take string for its configuration and has different approach to the data grouping. But in my case It worth all the time I spent :)